# NFluent library - List of List comparison

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nfluent

I have problem checking equality of List of List using [NFluent](http://www.n-fluent.net/):

```cs
using NFluent;

[Fact]
public void CollectionTest()
{
    var a = new List<int> {1, 2};
    var b = new List<int> {3, 4};

    // List contains references to a and b
    var list1 = new List<List<int>> {a, b};
    Check.That(list1).ContainsExactly(a, b);  // OK
    Check.That(list1).ContainsExactly(new List<List<int>> {a, b});  // OK

    // List contains new instances of lists same as a and b
    var list2 = new List<List<int>>
    {
        new List<int> {1, 2}, // new instance, same as a
        new List<int> {3, 4}  // new instance, same as b
    };
    Assert.Equal(list2, new List<List<int>> { a, b });  // XUnit assert is OK
    Check.That(list2).ContainsExactly(a, b);  // Fail
    Check.That(list2).ContainsExactly(new List<List<int>> {a, b});  // Fail
}
```

**Problem:** Last two checks fail.

**Cause:** The problem is that `ContainsExactly` does compare lists by reference (like `Equals`), not value by value (like [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx) do).

**Workarounds:**

1. Use XUnit `Assert.Equal()` which handles sequences correctely.
2. Write custom subclass of List that implements `Equals()` using `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`

**Question**: I'd like to keep using [NFluent](http://www.n-fluent.net/), is there some easy way to make last two Checks working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: upgrade to NFluent 2.1+, comparison behaviour has been revised.